# Почему не работает z-index в данном примере?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, css3, html5

Почему серый квадрат не закрывает черного?

```css
#box {
  z-index: 1; // <-- если убрать то всё заработает
  margin: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#box::before, #box::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 80px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #333;
}

#box::before {
  z-index: -1;
}

#box::after {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: потому что before и after - считай что дочерние элементы и если родительскому элементу задавать z-index, то они будут отображаться поверх даже с отрицательным z-index

Comment: @yolosora выходит что его никак нельзя туда спрятать?

Comment: @Cristian ну вы сами в вопросе написали что нужно сделать чтобы спрятать)

Comment: @yolosora знаю, просто в моем проекте если не поставить `z-index` выше нуля то его закрывают другие объекты

Answer (score 2):

```css
   .wrap{
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 1;
    }
    #box {
   
      margin: 50px;
      background: #ccc;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #box::before, #box::after {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      top: -10px;
      left: 80px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      background: #333;
    }

    #box::before {
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #box::after {
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере у псевдоэлементов `:before` и `:after` не работает `z-index` потому, что у их родителя определен свой `z-index` равный 1, который по приоритету стоит выше. И зачем вам 2 псевдоэлемента с одинаковыми стилями?